# Is the following statement is True/false regarding similar matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is  the following  statement is True/false ?

let $A$ be  an $n \times n$  matrix  with complex entries . Then  A is  always similiar to an upper triangular matrix .

## My Attempt:

i thinks  this satement is false   because  for  example  i take
$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 \\0  & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and   upper triangular matrix .$B =\begin{bmatrix} 2& 0 \\0  & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Both  A and B  are not similar

is  it correct ??

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Jordan form${}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown....im not getting  can u elaborate more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)  happens to be an upper triangular matrix to which the given matrix is similar,  provided, for instance,  its characteristic polynomial splits (which it does over $\mathbb C$).